# Is it possible to say this?

Tags: grammar

**To say "I got greatly impressed ", could I say, 
"I got a great impression."**

Thank you.

The question is whether I could say it both ways.

Comment: Your logic is correct, but *greatly* is something like a "fancy" word. E.g. you might say "I greatly appreciate it" to express a lot of appreciation in a polite context.  *Got X-ed* most of the time is a very informal construction - opposite of fancy.  So they sound weird together.

Answer (score 1):

I would say.

> *I was very impressed*.  - for your first example.

Your second example sounds correct.

Comment: "I was greatly impressed" is also fine. The key is that you wouldn't say "got", you'd say "was".

Answer (score 0):

`I got greatly impressed` doesn't sound good because of *got*.

You can simply say , "I was.. " as per above response or even *I am ..*